# gtk_container_add function crashes

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I have the following line in my GTK code:

```
 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(main_wind_ob->stack),
                    GTK_WIDGET(main_wind_ob->product_ob->swindow));
```

Where `main_wind_on->stack` is a `GtkStack` acquired this way

```
main_wind_ob->stack = GTK_STACK(
                          gtk_builder_get_object (
                                    main_wind_ob->builder,
                                                  "stack"
                                                  )
                                  );
```

Where `main_wind_ob->builder` is a `GtkBuilder` object associated with a .`ui` file where a `GtkStack` container is declared with the ID `stack`.

`main_wind_ob->product_ob->swindow` is a `GtkScrolledWindow` acquired like this:

```
main_wind_ob->product_ob->swindow = 
     gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
```

I know neither `main_wind_ob->product_ob->swindow` or `main_wind_ob->stack` are not null as I've debugged and checked them.

What I wanted to do was make `swindow` be the child of the stack, but it just crashes when it reaches the `gtk_container_add` function call. I am not really sure why. Let me know if there is any extra details I can add to the post, thanks.

Comment: Yes it is a typo sorry

Comment: I fixed it in the post.

Comment: Did you tried to create it without the builder to check if the problem is not there?